# How to set filter to false in defaultColDef only where headerName === "Action" in ag-grid?

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am able to set filter via `gridOptions.defaultColDef.filter` but I can't find out how to set the value based on `headerName` value.

I've tried looping through `columnDefs` but filter doesn't exists on that type (even though it is settable in columndDefs when I use the component in my app).

```js
gridOptions.columnDefs?.forEach(colDef => { 
  if (colDef.headerName === "Action") colDef.filter = false
}
```

Any idea how to set set filter to `false` as default for `Action` column and having it `true` for all others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `filter` to false in the constructor of your component like you already are. The type error can be relived by setting the type of your `colDef` value to `any`, but the correct solution would be to set it to `ColDef` which can be imported like so:

```
import { ColDef } from 'ag-grid-community/dist/lib/main';

this.columnDefs?.forEach((colDef: ColDef) => { 
  if (colDef.headerName === "Action") {
    colDef.filter = false
  }
});
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-angular-hello-world-e5ebkh?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

Comment: Just tested it and it works! Thanks a lot! Interesting thing is that VSCode was saying me that colDef is of type ColDef but intensense offered limited options compared to the type of ColDef added via ag-grid-community lib.